# spaCy NLP word.pos returns digits instead of POS tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, part-of-speech

I am using spaCy library for POS tagging but when I run this code, it returns numbers in the place of the pos tags:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.fr.examples import sentences

nlp = spacy.load('en')
mystring = " I am missing my lovely family a lot."
exuu = nlp(mystring)
for word in exuu: 
  print(word.text, word.pos)
```

Here is how the output looks like:

```
102
I 94
am 99
missing 99
my 83
dear 83
family 91
a 89
lot 91
. 96
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the "wrong" attribute. `word.pos` returns the PoS tag id, not the PoS tag string. To do what you want, just replace `word.pos` with `word.pos_`.

The following code will work fine:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.fr.examples import sentences
nlp = spacy.load('en')
mystring = " I am missing my lovely family a lot."
exuu = nlp(mystring)
for word in exuu: 
  print(word.text, word.pos_)
```